# why plt.savefig() doesn't work? When save figure, latitude does not show while longitude show correctly

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I am plotting global distribution of precipitation. So my figure should have longitude on the x-axis and latitude on the y-axis.

The figure show correctly inside jupyter notebook, with latitude and longitude shown correctly as desired.

However, when saving the figure using plt.savefigure(), and check the saved figure, the latitude labels disappear...

Does anyone know the reason?

complete code is attached here for your reference.

```
import xarray as xr
import numpy as np
import glob
import copy
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.gridspec as gridspec

from matplotlib.ticker import (MultipleLocator, AutoMinorLocator)
import matplotlib.ticker as mticker
from cartopy.mpl.gridliner import LONGITUDE_FORMATTER, LATITUDE_FORMATTER
import pandas as pd
import cartopy.crs as ccrs
%matplotlib inline

dpi = 100

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(1600/dpi, 1600/dpi), dpi=dpi) 

spec = gridspec.GridSpec(ncols=2, nrows=4,figure=fig,left=0.15,bottom=0.1,right=0.7,top=0.9)

spec.update(wspace=0.2,hspace=0.3)

ax = []

for ii in range(8):

    if ii <= 1:
        ax.append(fig.add_subplot(spec[0, ii],projection=ccrs.PlateCarree(central_longitude=180.0))) #,frameon=False)

    elif (ii >=2) and (ii <=3):
        ax.append(fig.add_subplot(spec[1, ii-2],projection=ccrs.PlateCarree(central_longitude=180.0))) #,frameon=False)
    
    elif (ii >=4) and (ii <=5):
        ax.append(fig.add_subplot(spec[2, ii-4],projection=ccrs.PlateCarree(central_longitude=180.0))) #,frameon=False)
    
    elif ii>=6:
        ax.append(fig.add_subplot(spec[3, ii-6],projection=ccrs.PlateCarree(central_longitude=180.0))) #,frameon=False)
    
    ax[-1].coastlines(resolution='110m',linewidth=0.8,color='black',linestyle='solid',alpha=0.7)
    ax[-1].set_global()
    ax[-1].set_title('',loc='left')
    ax[-1].set_extent([0.,357.5,-90,90],crs=ccrs.PlateCarree())

    gl = ax[-1].gridlines(crs=ccrs.PlateCarree(), draw_labels=True,linewidth=2, color='gray', alpha=1.0, linestyle='--')
    gl.top_labels = False
    gl.left_labels= True
    gl.right_labels=False
    gl.bottom_labels=True
    gl.xlines = False
    gl.ylines = False
    gl.xlocator = mticker.FixedLocator([-120,-60,180,120,60])
    gl.ylocator = mticker.FixedLocator([-90,-60,-30,0,30,60,90])
    gl.xformatter = LONGITUDE_FORMATTER
    gl.yformatter = LATITUDE_FORMATTER


plt.savefig("***.jpg",bbox_inches='tight',dpi=300,pad_inches=0.15)
```

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Please make a [mcve], and make sure it's minimal, so that we can easily try and reproduce the problem.

Comment: See if calling `plt.tight_layout()` before saving the figure helps.

Comment: a minimal reproducible example is attached.

Comment: Adding the imports would be useful. I think you use basemap or cartopy for the coastlines, but which one? Please show the necessary import statements.

Comment: see solution at https://github.com/SciTools/cartopy/issues/1794